# pointer problems?

Tags: c++

`buffer` is a protected `void*` part of my class.

```
void* ptr;
ptr= buffer;

if(ptr == pvTxt)
  return ptr; 

while (*((unsigned char*)ptr) || *(((unsigned char*)ptr)+1))
  ((unsigned char*)ptr)++;

return *((unsigned char*)ptr)+1;
```

Everything up to the:

```
((unsigned char*)ptr)++;

return *((unsigned char*)ptr)+1;
```

is fine but I know there is  something wrong with the casting?

Also in my main I have:

```
g_pvTxt = new unsigned char[BUFSIZE];  
memset (g_pvTxt,0,BUFSIZE);
```

Given the question above how do I append an array. Create an array/append to it. Can't use `std::vector` because it's an embedded system

To further explain the loop:

After an txt entry there is a null termination. At the end of all entries there is a double null. So, in the while loop if the value the pointer is pointing at is false (either 0 or 00) or `ptr || ptr+1`, it will increment the counter until it gets to the next spot where I can append values.

Comment: `(ptr = Txt)` looks wrong. Should it be `==`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just make the cast to `unsigned char*` *only once*?

```
unsigned char* ptr= static_cast<unsigned char*>(buffer);

if(ptr == pvTxt)
    return ptr; 

while (ptr[0] || ptr[1]) // *(ptr+1) would work as well
    ptr++;
return *ptr+1;
```

If you want to append to a buffer, and cannot use `std::vector` you can do something similar: allocate a bigger buffer, copy everything over and delete the old buffer.

Comment: Because I don't know what type my value is going to be. Also to further explain the loop, After an txt entry there is a null termination. At the end of all entries there is a double null. So, in the while loop if the value the pointer is pointing at is false either 0 or 00 it will increment the counter until it gets to the next spot where i can append values

Comment: @WutWut what do you mean you don't know what type it will be? You're casting to `unsigned char`, so you know that type. You cannot possibly cast without knowing the type.

Comment: I'm unsure of what type I will be receiving the data is why. one of my question is more syntax than anything

Comment: @WutWut: Ooops, sorry, for some reason I was thinking you could convert implicitly from `void*` to `unsigned char*` :). So, my idea was to make all the casts only once. Hope that's clearer now.

Comment: can you help me fix the verbose syntax?

Comment: @WutWut that's what I've been trying to do :) Sorry for the initial mixup. I edited the code to something that actually compiles now :)

Comment: Also, the while loop is wrong, I needs to be the value of the pointer and the value after the pointer is false then increment counter

Comment: @WutWut the code I have now is equivalent to the code you have. If it doesn't do what you expect, you need to make clear what you were expecting and what you're getting.

Comment: @WutWut: WHat he write is sematically equivalent to your example *ptr is equivalent to ptr[0]

Comment: it needs to be if the ptr value is 0 (aka false or ptr=0) || value of one character after the ptr(aka also false or ptr+1= 0 then increment the counter.

Comment: I appreciate your help by the way

Comment: `ptr+1` cannot be `0`. Do you mean to say `*ptr == 0` and `*(ptr + 1) == 0`? If so, **that's exactly what I have in my code**.

Comment: oh okay... I just thought the ptr[0] || ptr[1] was while true or false. In my example there can be 00 at the end of all the entries. but 0 after each individual entry

Comment: `ptr[0]` is just a shortcut for `*(ptr + 0)`, which is the same as `*ptr`. And `ptr[1]` is a shortcut for `*(ptr + 1)`. You can write them like that if you prefer, because they're exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

I think you blew it before then.

`if(ptr = Txt)` is assigning Txt to ptr and then testing whether the value is null or not.

So the previous statement assigning `ptr= buffer;` has no effect.

And you'll never get past the first `return` so long as Txt has a value coming in.

Comment: Your so right! thanks for the find. I changed that statement to be if(ptr == pvTxt)

Comment: @0A0D -- Sorry, but if you knew anything about TTYs you'd know it should be 0D0A. ;)

Comment: @DanielRHicks: I do know and I did it on purpose. I used to work with a lot of serial devices and one reversed the carriage return, line feed on me one time (chinese knockoff) that I felt compelled to change my nick to 0A0D.

Comment: Yeah, but whenever a program produced LF/CR it screwed up printing on the TTY something fierce because the carriage didn't have time to return before the first character of the next line struck.  Was hard enough getting the dashpots adjusted so straight CR/LF would work without misaligning the first character.

Answer (score 0):

Also be careful your scan or your response doesn't walk off the end of `buffer`.

I think you mistyped the variable names from your main example, but if you need to resize g_pvTxt you need to use "new" to get one of the newer size (current + append amount) then copy the two pieces to the new one manually, then discard the old array(s).